# Mass Lead Conversion Error

Tags: error, lead-conversion, invalid, reference, key

I have written the common lead conversion snippets within for loop and I got this Error. Yes following code creates Account and Contacts properly but it doesnt create any Opportunity.

**ERROR :**

> ConvertLead failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []

**Here Is my Code**

```
Database.LeadConvert objLeadConvert = new Database.LeadConvert();
        LeadStatus convertStatus = [Select Id, MasterLabel from LeadStatus where IsConverted=true limit 1];
        List<Database.LeadConvert> leadsToConvert = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();

        for (Lead myLead : selectedItems)
        {   //From the information of first lead create new account
            Account objAccount1= new Account();
            objAccount1.Name = myLead.Company;
            objAccount1.Phone = myLead.Phone;
            objAccount1.BillingCity = myLead.City;
            objAccount1.BillingCountry = myLead.Country;
            objAccount1.BillingPostalCode = myLead.PostalCode;
            objAccount1.BillingState = myLead.State;
            objAccount1.BillingStreet = myLead.Street;
            objAccount1.Fax = myLead.Fax;
            objAccount1.Rating = myLead.Rating;
            objAccount1.NumberOfEmployees = myLead.NumberOfEmployees;
            objAccount1.Website = myLead.Website;
            insert objAccount1;

            //From the information of first lead create new Contact
            Contact objContact1=new Contact();
            objContact1.FirstName=myLead.FirstName;
            objContact1.LastName=myLead.LastName;
            **objContact1.AccountId=objAccount1.id;**
            insert objContact1;

            objLeadConvert.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
            objLeadConvert.setLeadId(myLead.Id);
            objLeadConvert.setAccountId(objAccount1.id);
            objLeadConvert.setContactId(objContact1.id);
            objLeadConvert.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(false);
            objLeadConvert.setOpportunityName(myLead.Company);
            if (objAccount.OwnerId != null)
            {
                objLeadConvert.setOwnerId(objAccount.OwnerId);
            }
            System.Debug('------ Leads to Convert---'+objLeadConvert);
            leadsToConvert.add(objLeadConvert);
            System.Debug('------ListLeadstoConvert---'+leadsToConvert);


            try{
                ConvertResult= Database.convertLead(objLeadConvert,true);
               return new PageReference('/');// + listConvertResult[0].getContactId());
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
}
```

Comment: Where you populating the `selectedItems` list?

Comment: I have used standard Controller, and am assiging selected leads into "selectedItems", It shows selectedItems properly on VF page too.

Comment: And there is no any other Trigger or Validations on Lead or anyother objects.

Comment: objContact1.AccountId=objAccount1.id;   I have edited question & made this line bold, Is this Mapping causing an any issue ????